# Create bitmap in ndk level and display

Tags: android, bitmap, android-ndk

I want to create one bitmap and display it on screen by using ndk code, can anybody tel me how to do that. Sample code is good to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Gingerbread, NativeWindow is your choice to display a bitmap on screen from ndk.

android-ndk-r7b/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include/android/native_window.h

Looking for the two functions below,
    int32_t ANativeWindow_lock(ANativeWindow* window, ANativeWindow_Buffer* outBuffer,
        ARect* inOutDirtyBounds);
    int32_t ANativeWindow_unlockAndPost(ANativeWindow* window);

It looks very much like java Canvas at android SDK level, right?

To use nativeWnd, you have to pass down a jobject of java SurfaceHolder to ndk, then acquire on the surface to make a nativeWnd.

Then, use ANativeWindow_setBuffersGeometry to setup frame size and color format

Then, ANativeWindow_lock to lock the surface

Then, do your picture bitblt

At last, ANativeWindow_unlockAndPost - your bitmap is on screen

You can also search the Internet to find sample code using native window.